# Google Sheets conditional formating based on % of another value

Tags: google-sheets, percentage, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have the following data:

[image: sheets table]

What I want to do is based on the values in column B (Planned) change the color of the background of cells in column C (Done). Until Matt reaches 50% of his 100 hours I want the background to be green, when he reaches 75% yellow, and 100% red. Same for other people If Jasmine 50% of 40 -> green and so on.

Those numbers in the planned column will be typed in manually.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

#### green:

```
=C5/B5%<=50
```

#### yellow:

```
=C5/B5%<=75
```

#### red:

```
=C5/B5%=100
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

This needs 3 conditional format rules in the following order (the order is important):

Apply all rules to the range `C5:C`

1. Custom formula is `=C5/B5 <= 0.5`, set background colour green
2. Custom formula is `=C5/B5 <= 0.75`, set background colour yellow
3. Custom formula is `=C5/B5 <= 1`, set background colour red